# React app reports unused image, but it actually was used

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and have created a very simple app. Below is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import snake from "./snake.png";

class Mouse extends Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.outer(this.state);
    }

    state = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    };

    mouse_handler(e) {
        this.setState({
            x: e.clientX,
            y: e.clientY
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouse_handler.bind(this));
    }
}

class ShowMousePosition extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Mouse outer={(state) => {
            return <div>x: {state.x}, y: {state.y}</div>
        }} />
    }
}

class Snake extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Mouse outer={(state) => {
            return <img src="{snake}" alt="" style={{
                position: "absolute",
                left: state.x,
                top: state.y,
            }} />
        }} />
    }
}

class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <ShowMousePosition />
            <Snake />
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Parent />, document.getElementById("root")
);
```

When I run the code, I can only see the mouse coordinates in the page like this:

[image]

But the snake image is not display at all. And there is even a warning message in the console:

> Line 4:8:  'snake' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

I have used the variable as you can see in `<img src="{snake}" ...`. Why this happens and how can I fix this issue?
Thanks.

Btw, I'm sure the image `snake.png` exists and it's at the `src` folder, just as `index.js`.

Comment: Typo?  `src="{snake}"` looks like it should be `src={snake}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the quotes around the curly braces in `src`:

`return <img src="{snake}" alt="" style={{`

```
class Snake extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Mouse outer={(state) => {
            return <img src={snake} alt="" style={{
                position: "absolute",
                left: state.x,
                top: state.y,
            }} />
        }} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, d'oh! Sorry for the stupid question... and thanks for your quick answer!